# Wordpress custom submenu layout

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout, submenu

How can I completely change the layout of the submenu in WP?
Normally WP generates menu as UL > LI > UL > LI. but I need to change it to: UL > LI > DIV > ... > DIV > UL > ...
So there must be additional elements/wrappers to submenu. These wrappers also must contain custom CSS classes.
Is there a way to do this by some hooks or with some plugin?

The output should look like this

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="..."></a>
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="section">
          <div class="title"><a href="..."></a></div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="..."></a></li>
            ...
            <li><a href="..."></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <div class="title"><a href="..."></a></div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="..."></a></li>
            ...
            <li><a href="..."></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="..."></a>
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="section">
          <div class="title"><a href="..."></a></div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="..."></a></li>
            ...
            <li><a href="..."></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
          <div class="title"><a href="..."></a></div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="..."></a></li>
            ...
            <li><a href="..."></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the template where your menu is displayed (probably *header.php*), and locate the `wp_nav_menu` function. Add or update the arguments `items_wrap`, `before` and `after` like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu' => 'your menu',
    // [...] existing menu options
    'items_wrap' => '<div><ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul></div>', // will put a div on ul
    'before' => '<div>', // before the link
    'after' => '</div>' // after the link
));
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters

Comment: You're sure you edited the right menu in the right file? Try to echo stuff after to check if you make change on the right menu.

Comment: Yes it is correct menu.`<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
         'container' => '',
         'container_class' => '',
         'theme_location' => 'top',
         'items_wrap' => '<div><ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul></div>', // will put a div on ul
         'before' => '<div>', // before the link
         'after' => '</div>' // after the link
        ));
        ?>`

Comment: Check in your _functions.php_ if there is any filter applied on `wp_page_menu_args`.

Comment: Yes there was `wp_page_menu_args` filter. I have removed it and now `items_wrap` works, but the result is DIV > UL > LI > UL > LI and not UL > LI > DIV > DIV > UL.

Comment: Please edit your original question to add the current HTML and the desired HTML output as I don't get where you want that div's - is it supposed to be around the link, inside the link, just around the submenu... ? An exemple of what you want exactly will make it easier to help.